# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open.'

Tags: c#, .net, executescalar

I am developing a program in C # with .NET and MySQL databases.
I need the user image to be visible once the user is logged in, for which I have a LONGBLOB type column called 'Image'. The login process was good, but the following error occurred

```
Connection must be valid and open.
```

I'm using the following code to select from the database:

```
MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("select `user Image` from `userdb` where `username` = @img", con);
        
        command1.Parameters.Add("@img", MySqlDbType.Blob);
        
        command1.Parameters["@img"].Value = Admin;

        byte[] img = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();

        if (img == null)
        {
            pic_profilePic.Image = null;
        }
        else
        {
            var DATA = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
            var stream = new MemoryStream(DATA);
            pic_profilePic.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
```

Despite changing the column type into binary and varbinary, I still got the same error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, according to the exception, the connection you are passing as the second parameter to `MySqlCommand` is not open. Did you call the `Open()` method on it before you passed it to `MySqlCommand`? Unfortunately, you didn't post the relevant part of the code in your question - where is the declaration of the `con` variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=dbuser;password=s$cret;database=testdb";

var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
con.Open(); //did you open after you initialize the connection?
```

Please check your code to open your connection

Also remember to close it after you are done

```
con.Close();
```